# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list php javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a PHP project and I need to echo the dynamic confirmation text. I am trying with following code:

```
<a href="#" onclick='return confirm(<?php echo $instance->translator->__("Are you sure you want to delete this video?"); ?>)'> Remove</a>
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

how can I solve this ?

Comment: where do you get the error, in JS console, on page or in some server log? Have you tried to separate the frontend and backend bits? If that's a backend problem, please edit your post accordingly, otherwise show the actual HTML bit that comes on frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes in the JS/HTML too

```
<a href="#" 
onclick="return confirm('<?php echo $instance->translator->__("Are you sure you want to delete this video?"); ?>')"> Remove</a>
```

Alternative

```
<? $areyousure = $instance->translator->__("Are you sure you want to delete this video?"); ?>
<a href="#" 
onclick="return confirm('<?= $areyousure ?>')"> Remove</a>
```

Even better:

```
<div id="linkContainer">
  <a href="#" data-id="<?= $idtoremove"?> class="remove">Remove</a>
</div>
<script>
const areyousure = '<? $instance->translator->__("Are you sure you want to delete this video?"); ?>';


document.getElementById('linkContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('remove')) {
    if (confirm(areyousure)) removeSomething(tgt.dataset.id)
  }
});
```